# Question about using dimensional analysis on an analytically derived equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, viscosity

Say we have the following analytical relationship for a force:

[image]

Say we want to non-dimensionalise this equation. I would do this by writing:
$$F_L = f(\mu, V, R_1, R_2) $$
... and going from there.

This gives me:
$$\frac{F_L}{\mu V} = f\left(\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)$$

However, the mark scheme for this problem states the following non-dimensional relationship:
[image]

We could get to this result by saying:
$$F_L = f(\mu, V, R_1, R_2, \rho) $$

My question is - **if we know analytically that the force does not depend on density, why is density included in the dimensional analysis?** How is that correct?

**EDIT - MORE CONTEXT**

The question:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Part (c) below results in the analytical relationship I'm referring to

Part (d) requires dimensional analysis so that we can equate the dimensionless parameters in the model and in real life for dynamic similarity. My question is about part (d)

Comment: Without more context for what you're doing in the course and the wording of the question I'm not sure there's a single correct answer to your question. There's not a unique way to write a dimensionful expression as a dimensional quantity times a dimensionless quantity. (For example, in the mark scheme, why use $R_2$ and not $R_1$?). However, from the handwritten comments, I would guess that the intention of this problem was for you to derive the Reynolds number or show how $F_L$ depends on the Reynolds number (although perhaps that wasn't clear from the way the question was worded).

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your reply. Please see my edits - I've included more context about the question. Do let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed very helpful. The question is asking how $F_L$ scales with the linear dimension ($R_1$ or $R_2$). The issue with your original answer is that you can't use it to determine how $F_L$ scales with $R_1$ or $R_2$. The question is asking you to choose $V$ to guarantee "dynamic similarity", which is why you need the Reynold's number. (For dynamic similarity, you choose $V$ to keep the Reynold's number fixed). Given the Reynold's number, you can calculate how $F_L$ scales with $R_2$, which is what the mark scheme does.

Comment: @Andrew So would it be correct to say that though density doesn't appear in the analytical expression, we can still include it in the dimensional analysis because the resulting dimensionless parameter (i.e. Reynold's number) is more "useful" than the ratio of lengths in my proposed answer (i.e. $R_2/R_1$ doesn't tell us anything about $V$, which is what we are after)?

Comment: @Andrew Also, what's happened to $R_1$ in their non-dimensional equation with Reynolds number? Would it be arguably more correct to say non-dimensional force is a function of Reynolds number AND a ratio of lengths (i.e. 6 variables, including density, 3 dimensions, so 3 dimensionless groups)?

Comment: They are.scaling the whole sysem, and the lneegth scale in the renylond's number is just a characteristic length, so they ocould have used $R_1$ or $R_2$.

Comment: The reason the Renyold's number is relevant is the requirement of dynamical similarity.